# Is correct to use ng-show and ng-hide on the same DOM element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was wondering if is a good practice to use ng-show and ng-hide on the same DOM element.

It seems a better idea, instead of using multiple conditions, some of which negated, in a single ng-show.

Let me know.
Thanks!

PS: here an example

```
<div ng-show="isBlonde" ng-hide="hasBlueEye">Mary is blonde and she has green eyes</div>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Absolutely not.**

First of all, the two directives can trip over each other( see this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/edE7M/), as provided by **[Joel Skrepnek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/561534/joel-skrepnek)**), and is generally just bad design.

You can use a function, another field or just some more inline-logic.

***Inline-Logic:***

```
<div ng-show="isBlonde && !hasBlueEye">Mary is blonde and she has green eyes</div>
```

***Field:***

```
<div ng-show="shouldShowThisDiv">Mary is blonde and she has green eyes</div>
```

***Function***

```
<div ng-show="shouldShowThisDiv()">Mary is blonde and she has green eyes</div>

$scope.shouldShowThisDiv = function(){
    return $scope.isBlonde && !$scope.hasBlueEye;
}
```

**My recommendation** would be to use either another **field** or a **function**, if there are more than 2 values that needs to be checked.

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive explanation.

Comment: @Andre Thanks. For my solution ng-hide="condition1 || !condition2" worked.

Answer (score 6):

Use one but not both. Choose the one which makes the expression the most readable.

Otherwise you could end up with:

```
<div ng-show='true' ng-hide='true'></div>
```

Comment: This makes sense to me. Thanks for making me note this potential problem.

Comment: I think this solution is not ideal